# MediaWiki need a page to display information from multiple templates

Tags: mediawiki

Hello and in advance I appreciate all the help,

I am new to MediaWiki and understand how to create a Template page but what if i need a page to display information from multiple templates. How would this work?

Meaning I have one page titled say "Description" and I would need that page to host the description of many projects. Is this possible? I have looked at the templates but alone it doesn't seem possible.

I know I must be missing something here. I read the documentation and its great but it doesn't explain how to link the information to well.

Thank You

Comment: I made some headway doing some research. So i am going to pass a parameter to the template and then use parser functions to determine which nested template to use. Is this correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might be misunderstanding the question, but you can put any number of  templates on a page:

```
== Description ==
{{project1-description}}
{{project2-description}}
...
```